# CakePHP testing: data successfully saved despite foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, cakephp

I am unit-testing my app's controller, which saves data from a REST call. I pass data with a foreign key `vehicle_id = 99`, which does not exist in Fixture data, but in the test it is saved successfully! This is not what I want - I want the save to fail.

Here is my Fixture and model:

```
class RouteFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public $import = array('model' => 'Route');
}

class Route extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Vehicle' => array(
            'className' => 'Vehicle',
            'foreignKey' => 'vehicle_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `routes` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `vehicle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
 KEY `vehicle_id` (`vehicle_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `routes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicles` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `routes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And here is what I find in the database after save in the test

```
    (int) 1 => array(
            'Route' => array(
                    'id' => '2',
                    'account_id' => '0',
                    'created' => '2015-01-17 05:05:51',
                    'vehicle_id' => '99'
            ),
            'Account' => array(
                    'id' => null
            ),
            'Vehicle' => array(
                    'id' => null,
                    'name' => null,
                    'account_id' => null
            ),
            'Address' => array()
    )
```

Please advise why the constraint is not checked in the test. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that [**foreign key checks**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) are enabled?

Comment: I guess you need to define the schema in RouteFixture instead of importing the model.

Comment: @ndm - yes, they are

Comment: @bancer - tried it - doesn't help. It seems like Cake's Fixture engine does not import foreign key constraints, because the PHP table definition I got with `cake bake` does not include any foreign key references. I guess this must be the source of the problem